# automount: Another automount is running

Tags: macos, automount, nfs

I'm trying to reload NFS mounts on my machine. What has worked in the past is:

```
sudo dscl .
delete Mounts/
exit
sudo autmount -vc
```

But now I get the error:

```
automount: Another automount is running
```

Doing a

```
sudo ps -ax | grep automount
```

shows there's only one process (besides the grep command itself) that contains "automount":

```
admin% sudo ps -ax | grep -i automount
59770 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/automount
60201 ttys018    0:00.00 grep -i automount
```

I've tried killing it and rerunning `sudo automount -vc` and `sudo automount -vcu`, but no luck.

Has anyone else encountered this error message, or have any ideas on how to fix it?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite) on my local machine. If it's useful at all, the remote file server is running Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Should the title of this question be: "How can I fix automount: Another automount is running?"

Answer (score 1):

I see a process autofsd, which is performing the auto mount, but I run Mac OS X 10.12.6 so maybe that is different.

When I run automount it updates the mounts (from the auto_master file)

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing with autofs on OSX and run into this error occasionally.
Try the following commands (the suggestion came from [this blog](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/07/mount-various-file-system-with-autofs-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#mount-sshfs-with-autofs))

```
launchctl stop com.apple.automountd
launchctl stop com.apple.autofsd
launchctl start com.apple.autofsd
launchctl start com.apple.automountd
sudo automount -vc
```